# 2-layover trip in europe with F1 visa

Tags: schengen, transit-visas, layovers, f1-visas

I currently hold a US F1 visa on my Iranian passport, and I've booked a flight from NYC to Tehran.
The problem is that the trip is from JFK (US) to ZRH (Switzerland), from ZRH to FRA (Germany), and then from FRA to IKA (Iran).
I'm wondering if I can stay in the international area of the airport for the domestic flight (ZRH to FRA) because I don't have a Schengen visa.
If not, do I need a transit Schengen or another kind?
I'm not sure if getting the visa would be easier/cheaper than canceling/rebooking the flight.

edit: turns out that even a transit visa wouldn't work for 2 layovers, so I contacted the booking website and canceled the flight, fortunately with a full refund.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a flight within the Schengen area, as you have planned, you need a full Schengen visa for the day(s) you will be in the Schengen area. There is no 'international area' option for those flights.
And the transit visa is only for transits within one airport.

I think rebooking the flight is the best option, as getting a visa is not cheap and not guaranteed to work out.
In the comment on this answer, @Tor-Einar Jambo does not agree with me, he says that a Schengen visa costs €60, rebooking is likely more expensive.

When you work out your flights, check them on an IATA checking site.
[Like this one](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm).

Comment: The Schengen visa will cost €60. Unless OP has a full price ticket, it will likely be (much) more expensive to change the ticket, if it is at all possible than to get the required visa.

Comment: My edit was a fix of the typo